# jquery display ajax response in next instance of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that uses while loop to display results.  If the user clicks the `evernote` button the information from the adjacent result is emailed using ajax.  I am trying to get the ajax response displayed the instance of the `div` with the class `sent_to_evernote` which is adjacent to the button that is clicked.

```
<td>
   <input type="button" class="evernote_todo" value="Evernote"  />
   <div class="sent_to_evernote"></div>
</td>
```

I know the ajax success is returning the correct response but I just can't get it to display.

```
success: function(response){
    if(response == 'sent'){
        $(this).parent('td').find('div.sent_to_evernote').html(response);
    }
}//end success
```

`this` is the Evernote button

Comment: can you display full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really haven't shown much code context but `this` is not a dom element inside a `$.ajax` callback.

There are several things you can do

One is store a variable reference of `this` inside your event handler, or pass `this` to the `context` option of `$.ajax`

```
$(selector).on('some_event', function(){
    var self = this; // one way - store reference outside of callback
    $.ajax({
       url: '....',
       context: this, // alternate way - pass in `this` as callback context
       success:function(response){
          if(response == 'sent'){
             // depending on approach use $(this) or $(self)  
             $(this).parent('td').find('div.sent_to_evernote').html(response);
          }
       }
    })

})
```